# Singular precision matrix warning in R

Tags: r, nlme, mgcv

I'm running different model of this form:

```
gamm(H_1_3~ s(wcomp.x.cum, bs='cr')+s(wcomp.y.cum, bs='cr')+s(h_AST, bs='cr'), 
           na.action=na.omit,data=lag4_1DAY, method='REML',  weights=vf)
```

R doesn't throw me an Error (i.e. I have an output) but I have a warning like this one:

```
Warning message:
In logLik.reStruct(object, conLin):
  Singular precision matrix in level -3, block 1
```

1. what does it means?
2. is it a problem or can I live with it?

Comment: It is interesting that it is only a warning and not an error. So the function was apparently able to build a fit. Do the results look sensible?

Comment: looks like an overfitted model...

Comment: @BondedDust What do you mean with 'Do the results look sensible?'

Comment: Users may try different optimizers and/or optimization methods if warnings of this kind are encountered.